# Uploading app to test flight throws app icon missing validation error

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to upload to a xamarin ios application to test flight but sometimes it throws asset validation failed error. After trying multiple times it will automatically approve it. I don't change anything. Can anyone help me?[image: attached image of the error]

I try to upload publish it multiple times but it gives an asset validation error.

Comment: Please do not post errors as images

Comment: Could the App icon be seen when you install your app on your device?

Comment: Yes. I can see the app icon and it is rendering perfectly

Comment: Have you submitted app for review? If so, you should add the version number.

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry I was building the application in debug mode and then trying to upload the debug build.

I was tinkering with the project and then came across this discovery, so silly of me. But fortunately, I found the solution.

Just go to - Config manager -> Select release and then rebuild your application -> Archive it.